# How can I make the transaction rollback if the API call fails and vice versa?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, transactions, stripe-payments

Two things I want:

a) I want to be able to save a record in the db only if the API call succeeds

b) I want to execute the API call only if the db record saves successfully

The goal, is to keep data stored locally (in the DB) consistent with that of the data on Stripe.

```
@payment = Payment.new(...)

begin
  Payment.transaction do
    @payment.save!

    stripe_customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(manager.customer_id)

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      amount:   @plan.amount_in_cents,
      currency: 'usd',
      customer: stripe_customer.id
    )
  end
# https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors
rescue Stripe::CardError, Stripe::InvalidRequestError, Stripe::APIError => error
  @payment.errors.add :base, 'There was a problem processing your credit card. Please try again.'
  render :new
rescue => error
  render :new
else
  redirect_to dashboard_root_path, notice: 'Thank you. Your payment is being processed.'
end
```

The above following will work, because if the record (on line 5) doesn't save, the rest of the code doesn't execute.

But what if I needed the `@payment` object saved after the API call, because I need to assign the `@payment` object with values from the API results. Take for example:

```
@payment = Payment.new(...)

begin
  Payment.transaction do
    stripe_customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(manager.customer_id)

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      amount:   @plan.amount_in_cents,
      currency: 'usd',
      customer: stripe_customer.id
    )

    @payment.payment_id = charge[:id]

    @payment.activated_at = Time.now.utc
    @payment.save!
  end
# https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors
rescue Stripe::CardError, Stripe::InvalidRequestError, Stripe::APIError => error
  @payment.errors.add :base, 'There was a problem processing your credit card. Please try again.'
  render :new
rescue => error
  render :new
else
  redirect_to dashboard_root_path, notice: 'Thank you. Your payment is being processed.'
end
```

You notice `@payment.save!` happens after the API call. This could be a problem, because the API call ran, before the DB tried to save the record. Which could mean, a successful API call, but a failed DB commit.

Any ideas / suggestions for this scenario?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't execute API => DB and DB => API at the same time (sounds like an infinite execution conditions), at least I can't image how you can achieve this workflow. I understand your data consistency needs, so I propose:

- Check if record is valid `@payment.valid?` (probably with a custom method like `valid_without_payment?`)
- Run api call
- Save record (with `payment_id`) only if api call succeds

Alternatively:

- Save record without `payment_id`
- Run api call
- Update record with `payment_id` (api response) if call succeds
- Run a task (script) periodically (cron) to check inconsistent instances (`where(payment_id: nil)`) and delete it

I think both options are acceptable and your data will remain consistent.

Comment: Right, but I would want to check if `@payment.valid?` after the API call, not before, since I would need to assign `payment_id`. And even still, the API call would still execute first, before the DB record is saved, which defeats the goal

Comment: You want to call api and then save to db (API => DB) and at the same time, save to db and then call api (DB => API). I think it's not possible. So that's why I propose to: 1) check if valid (probably with a custom method like `valid_without_payment?`), 2) call api and 3) save (with payment_id from api response) only if api returns ok.

Comment: And what if the save (with payment_id) fails?

Comment: If payment is valid and api succeds (returns a valid id), save with payment_id should not fails. You can't achieve A before B and B before A at the same time, at least I can't image how. A different approach can be similar to your first code block: 1) save record (without payment_id), 2) call api and 3) update record with payment_id. You can supplement this logic running a rake task periodically (cron) to check unconsistent records (without payment_id) and delete it.

Comment: would that make sense `validates :payment_id, presence: true`, and run the api call in a before_validation callback ?